# Update MySql Table from CSV using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need a PHP script which will update existing MySQL table getting data from a CSV. Table field `hasweb` need to be updated comparing a field `consultant_id`.

So MySql query should be

```
UPDATE user_data 
SET hasweb="something" 
WHERE consultant_id = "something";
```

Please help me to write a PHP script which can execute this query as many times as needed, depending upon CSV data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written little php scripts to accomplish this many times and there are many ways go to about it:

The best according to my experience is to use CSV functions provided by PHP, take a look at [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), because manually opening file and reading it line by line and parsing can cause complications.

Now you just loop through all the rows in csv and prepare query dynamically and execute it, for example (assuming that column 0 has IDs and column 1 has "hasweb")

```
<?php
    if (($handle = fopen("input.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            mysql_query(UPDATE user_data SET hasweb="{$data[1]}" WHERE consultant_id = "{$data[0]}"); 
        }
    fclose($handle);
    }
?>
```

Hope that helps. If still stuck, Please ask me :)

Comment: Hey @BlackDivine - why are you using 1000 for the length in that fgetcsv function? I'm trying to do the same thing that the original poster wanted to do and I'm curious. Thank you!!

Comment: Because it's a safe limit, unless you have a line longer than 1k chars. Be aware that second parameter (1000 in this case) is not the length of whole file, but a single line.

Quoting official php docs "Must be greater than the longest line (in characters) to be found in the CSV file (allowing for trailing line-end characters). It became optional in PHP 5. Omitting this parameter (or setting it to 0 in PHP 5.0.4 and later) the maximum line length is not limited, which is slightly slower. "

Answer (score 1):

You can use php function fgetcsv.

you can get all data from CSV file into php by using this function. 
for example,

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("your_file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        $SQL = 'UPDATE table_name SET col1=val1 WHERE con1';
        execute($SQL); 
    }
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

see this function: http://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.fgetcsv.php