# UPDATE MySQL table from a CSV using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, sql-update

I found and followed the directions contained within this StackOverflow thread: [Update MySql Table from CSV using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950104/update-mysql-table-from-csv-using-php)

I've got an error somewhere that I'm unable to detect, I think there's a problem with my query, which works fine in actual MySQL but seems to not quite translate to PHP.

In short, I'm trying to `UPDATE` the value of several rows within a single table (`catalog_product_entity_varchar`) with CSV column `$data[1]`, but only where certain skus are concerned AND `attribute_id` = 523 AND `entity_id` matches `$data[0]` of my `CSV`. Here's my code (actual PW/username, etc, obviously removed)

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","some_db");

    if (!$con){
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    if (($file = fopen("upload.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

        while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {

            $sql = "UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar 
                            JOIN catalog_product_flat_1
                            ON catalog_product_flat_1.entity_id = catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id 
                            SET catalog_product_entity_varchar.value='{$data[1]}' 
                            WHERE catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id='{$data[0]}'
                            AND catalog_product_entity_varchar.attribute_id = 523
                            AND (catalog_product_flat_1.sku LIKE  '%PR%'
                                 OR catalog_product_flat_1.sku LIKE  '%PT%'
                                 OR catalog_product_flat_1.sku LIKE  '%PF%')";

            if (mysql_query($con,$sql)) {
                echo "Updated!";
            } else {
                echo "Error updating " . mysql_error();
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
```

It simply returns **"Error updating"** for every line of the spreadsheet. This query, when simply done in MySQL (without the PHP) and modified to have actual values instead of $data[1] or $data[0] works just fine. What am I missing?

If you're unclear of what I'm trying to achieve, I did post this question yesterday (trying to do it via pure mySQL) and there's more context here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170245/updating-a-joined-table-in-mysql-from-a-csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow.

So I feel stupid. Apparently mixing mysqli_connect and mysql_query doesn't work very well. Adding the "i" to the "mysql" of mysql_query solved it. Thanks for looking everyone!